# Administrative mail keeps coming for a person who moved out of Japan

Tags: relocation, japan, postal-system

I continue to receive administrative mail (mostly from insurance and city hall) addressed to a person who has left Japan already.

I scan and email her the content every time, but letters keep coming.
What is the recommended way to tell the senders that she is not in Japan anymore?

Comment: I don't know about Japan but probably it's the same as here in Germany. You can just write on the envolope "address unknown" and send it back to the sender.

Comment: How is this related to expatriation?

Comment: @Flimzy: The expatriate here is my friend. She switched countries several times. That's expatriation. If had moved within in Japan, she would have got registered to another city.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same as if the person has simply moved to a different address in Japan.  You ideally put a sticker on, or else in a bold colour, put 'no longer at this address' across the letter, and put it back in the mail. This will usually have it returned to sender in most countries.

Alternatively, go to a post office with the letters, hand them over and ask "please return to sender" (Sashidashinin ni hensou shite kudasai.).

(my Japanese isn't perfect, but that's the best I can do without kanji)